# Angular Popup Not Popping out

Tags: angular

Keeping well I hope

I am using Angular 12 but the pop-up dialog does not appear in a different window and I have done the below:

1. Import MatDialogModule in apps module and add it in Imports:

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

2. Create in my ts file specific to the pop-up the below

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
    import { PopupComponent } from './popup/popup.component';    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PopupService {
    
      constructor(private matPopup: MatDialog) { }  

    dialogOpen() {
        this.matPopup.open(PopupComponent, {
          disableClose: true,
          width: '400px',
          panelClass:'confirmcontainer',          
    
        });
      }      
    }
```

3. Inject the popup service in my delete button function ts file

```
    deleteBilling(id: string) {
    
        this.popupService.dialogOpen(); 

    }
```

4. adjust `popupcomponent` html file to show "It works"

The outcome of this is that it shows the message "It works" as part of the same form but not as a popup?

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: stackblitz please

Comment: maybe your PopupComponent located in another module? and u need to import this module as well?

Comment: Thanks - it is imported but not working still

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following path in `angular.json` file if not added already:

```
./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
```

> Make sure to restart `ng serve` to reload the `angular.json` file.

Or try importing the following path in `style.css` file if not imported already:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: Thanks - I restarted and it eventually worked... Appreciate it as it was not mentioned in the tutorial I was following